# Creating a new data frame from two existing data frame based on values from two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

**Input Data Frame**

DF 1 (example - nrow = 10)

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
  a       1       2    
  a       3       4    
  b       5       6    
  c       9      10
```

DF 2 (example - nrow = 20)

```
Col A | Col B | Col E
  a       1       22    
  a       31      41    
  a       3       63    
  b       5       6
  b       11      13   
  c       9       20
```

I want to create a third data set which contains each of the additional row found in the Data Frame 2 for the Col A and Col B entry.

**Output File** (nrow = 20-10 = 10)

```
Col A | Col B | Col E
  a       31      41    
  b       11      13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[!df1, on = .(ColA, ColB)]
#  ColA ColB ColE
#1:    a   31   41
#2:    b   11   13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), ColB = c(1L, 3L, 
5L, 9L), ColC = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
df2 <- structure(list(ColA = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), ColB = c(1L, 
31L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 9L), ColE = c(22L, 41L, 63L, 6L, 13L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 5):

```r
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("ColA", "ColB"))
#   ColA ColB ColE
# 1    a   31   41
# 2    b   11   13
```

---

Data:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), ColB = c(1L, 3L, 
5L, 9L), ColC = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
df2 <- structure(list(ColA = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), ColB = c(1L, 
31L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 9L), ColE = c(22L, 41L, 63L, 6L, 13L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```